# How to redirect all node aliases to <front>?

Tags: 7, uri, redirection, routes

I created a module with a `hook_menu()` to redirect every `$items[%node]` to `drupal_goto('<front>')`. Is it possible to do the same for every alias path and how would I do that?

The background is that it's a one-pager with all nodes displayed only on the `<front>` page. No single node should be viewed. Nevertheless every single node has a Facebook Like Button and so has to be like-able/share-able with Facebook. But that's another story, on the whole.

Comment: Sounds like you're about to commit SEO-suicide...I'm probably just not getting it but could you explain what you're trying to do in a bit more detail? If you're forwarding all node pages onto the front page, the individual Facebook like buttons will never be available to anyone...

Comment: The individual Facebook Like Button is made available through the view by adding a field for `content: path`and rewrite the result with the Facebook div and inserting a path token as URL.

Comment: I thought that would be too much detail here, but in the end the shared event URL should be called and the caller shall land on the `<front>` with the event toggled by JS.

Comment: Might I suggest a different approach? Install [Rabbit Hole](http://drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) to return a 404 on the full node pages, and set the path of the custom 404 to the front page. That should have exactly the same effect, with a lot less mess

Comment: Google bot and other robots does not interpret javascript. Not all humans have it turned on in their browsers. It could seriously handicap blind, for example. @Clive is right, it is a SEO suicide, but depending on jurisdiction you are risking discrimination lawsuits too.

Comment: The client doesn't care about SEO and unfortunatley neither about barrier-free internet. The people with JS turned off will simply land on the `<front>` and can read the teasers, that's okay.

Comment: @Clive - Do you mean the alias path by 'full node'?

Comment: @Mołot - Discrimination lawsuits???

Comment: Yep exactly. Be wary that whatever you end up doing here you're going to be fighting with Drupal to some degree, it's not really set up for that sort of workflow without customisation

Comment: Yep @koivo Disability Discrimination Act/Section 504/other applicable local law...They're extraordinarily rare in my experience, but it's _your_ head on the block if you fail to advise. Crazy world we live in.

Comment: What @Clive says, plus if you plan to ever be able to cooperate with any kind of government (even at local level) in European Union, you have to have AA accessibility level as defined by w3c. If you will get any income from cooperating with tax-funded institutions it opens a whole new law requirements labyrinth for you. I believe in other areas it's similar now. Side effect: good SEO required by law ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module you can implement a rule that looks like so:

```
{ "rules_redirect_all_node_aliases" : {
    "LABEL" : "Redirect all node aliases",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "init" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "text_matches" : {
          "text" : [ "site:current-page:path" ],
          "match" : "node\/\\d+$",
          "operation" : "regex"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "redirect" : { "url" : "my_homepage" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

It will redirect any path starting with `node/` to a path named `my_homepage` (adapt that path to fit your homepage path).

To experiment with this rule in your own site, just copy the entire Rules code above, and paste it in a new Rule in your own site, created via the "Import" function.

**Note**: A variation of this rule could be to replace the Rules Condition with something like "if the current path is not `my_homepage`" (in which case the same Rules Action will redirect to `my_homepage`.